# Problems with Fooman Speedster: 403 error + Verify Minification ERROR

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, js-css

I have a problem with Fooman Speedster
Self-test shows two errors:

1) Verify Permission ERROR (Step 2)
2) Verify Minification ERROR: there are no files starting with "minify_" in "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/minifycache" (Step 3)
[image]

With regard Verify Permission ERROR (Step 2) - site.com/lib/minify/m.php - 403 Forbidden

I do not find the answers to these errors in the Developer's Guide:

http://cdn.fooman.co.nz/media/custom/upload/UserManual-FoomanSpeedster.pdf
http://cdn.fooman.co.nz/media/custom/upload/TheUltimateGuidetoInstallingMagentoExtensions.pdf
http://store.fooman.co.nz/extensions/magento-extension-speedster.html

Please, any advice and suggestions!

```
Selftest failed with: Step 1 - OK
Verify Permission ERROR (Step 2)
Verify Minification ERROR: there are no files starting with "minify_" in "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/minifycache" (Step 3)
Step 4 - OK
Please read the manual for details.
Starting Fooman_Speedster_Model_Selftester
Default store loaded
Magento version: 1.9.0.1
Speedster DB version: Not installed
Speedster Config version: 3.0.14
Checking file locations
Checking rewrites
Checking database
Result: success
```

Comment: User Manual-Fooman Speedster, Page 8 from the first link you gave tells you how to manually test the installation and set permissions... Which is where you're failing. Follow the directions in the manual and it will work.